# When getting the time from an NTP server, what should an end user set in the refid and stratum field?

Tags: ntp

The title pretty much explains it.  I'm only using the NTP server as a time source, I only need accuracy to the 100µs level or so.

What is the best practice for what to use in the stratum and refid fields of the protocol?

I will be getting my time from the time.nist.gov server, so I don't know what the stratum of my upstream servers will be.

Comment: Are you asking if you can manually set the stratum level & ref id of your own server which is synced to an external server? You wouldn't normally 'set' anything - and I would use a closer/better external server than nist (remembering that ntpd best works with 3-5 servers to reference)

Comment: @user3788685: I'm trying to just be a client and get the time.  Not be a server at all.

Comment: Then I'm not sure I understand your question. As a client you don't set anything you simply receive that data from the upstream server.

Comment: @user3788685:  That fact isn't super clear in the documentation, or at least what I have been able to see.  If you write it up, I'll accept it.

Comment: No problem :) done with hopefully a helpful example. If you need help figuring any of the other bits out just drop me a comment or raise a new question and I'll be happy to help/add to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When connecting as a client those fields are populated from the upstream server you are receiving your time from.

As an example here is my output from  `ntpq -p` (Server data made anonymous)

```
 remote           refid          st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 PRIVATE         .STEP.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
-PRIVATE1        .GPS.            1 u   55   64  377   29.585    0.071   0.312
-PRIVATE2        .GPS.            1 u   40   64  377    9.468    0.209   0.129
-PRIVATE3        1.1.1.1          2 u   12   64  377    6.943   -0.270   0.142
-PRIVATE5        .PPS.            1 u   20   64  377   16.383   -0.531   0.197
+PRIVATE6        .DCFa.           1 u   22   64  377    8.661   -0.036   0.126
-ISP1            2.2.2.2          2 u   36   64  377   11.720   -0.027   0.280
#PRIVATE7        .GPS.            1 u   47   64  377   24.781   -1.405   1.118
+ISP2            .PPS.            1 u    4   64  377    6.012    0.062   0.154
-ISP3            .PPS.            1 u   14   64  377   13.993   -0.463   0.206
-ISP4            .CDMA.           1 u   57   64  377   71.712   -0.109   0.249
 ntp.mcast.net   .MCST.          16 u    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.002
 LOCAL(0)        .LOCL.          10 l  69d   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
xSHM(0)          .GPS.            0 l    9   16  377    0.000  -25.278   7.907
*SHM(1)          .PPS.            0 l   11   16  377    0.000   -0.030   0.060
```

The docs [here](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/ntpq.html) will help explain some more, but the basics are;

st = Stratum - This is how 'close' the server listed is from the actual time receiver. In my example take `PRIVATE6` the server it's self is a stratum 1 server getting its time directly from a stratum 0 device (in this case a DCFa receiver), but if you look to the bottom you see I have `SHM(1)` with a stratum of `0` as its a GPS PPS device directly connected to my server.

refid = Reference ID - This is where the server you are getting the time from is its self getting its time from. In my examples above most of those servers get there time from directly connected hardware, but if you look at `PRIVATE3` in my list you see it has an IP address as its reference source - that's because that server is relying on another server for its time (Rather an a 'real' clock of its own such as GPS/DCF/MSF)

Stratum levels are always increase by 1 the 'further' away from the time source you get.

GPS RX (S0) -> Server running the GPS (S1) -> a.n.other server (S2) -> end client.

If you are building a robust timing domain then ntp needs a *minimum* of 3 servers, and *ideally* 5 in order for it to work it's best and minimise any chances of being poisoned. (your time being pulled away from what is true by a couple of rogue servers) You should pick (if you can) servers that are close to you (as in round trip time) and servers which are ideally S2 or better. *I personally wouldn't use `time.nist.gov` or any of the other well known ntp servers as they are often too far away, have high load and poor RTT* If you have a look round you should be able to find some suitable servers, or for not much money you can build your own with a GPS receiver.

Comment: The special Refid ".STEP." can be kinda mysterious. There's a long thread at Cisco.com, suggesting that this means "the NTP server needed to adjust your local clock". In my opinion, this just means "the local ntpd is not able to contact that upstream server". In my case, I had two "client" boxes running ntpd - a third box in the LAN serving as an NTP server, and another NTP server in the DMZ. Now on one of the client-only boxes, the server in the DMZ had the ".STEP." RefID and a stratum 16. Guess what: the client's IPv4 config was missing a default gateway.

Comment: That SHM(0) refclock with an "X" mark (falseticker) is kinda funny :-) Just a little bit though. The "SHM" stands for a Shared Memory data exchange mechanism between ntpd and the "refclock driver". And this is clearly a refclock driver for the Time of Day information obtained from the USB-attached receiver. Which need not be extremely precise if accompanied by a dedicated PPS signal - that's the next refclock instance on the very next line. The Pulse Per Second signal is ultimately precise, and is therefore tagged "*" = the current syspeer.

Comment: The `SHM(0)` on that box is a serial input `NMEA` GPS string which is rather jittery. the offset could possibly be tamed further with some tweaking of the `time1` param in the conf file.